# Sitecore + Mvc Application. Proper redirection without losing Google indexing. sitecoredomain.com/mvcapp

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, sitecore, reverse-proxy, google-indexing-api

I have big dilemma and I need help.

Basically we have `sitecore web app` this is our `main` web service. Currently my app is working with the main app via `.html` static pages(it works as SPA, JS calls backend with needed html content).
But database I work with grows bigger, and to access certain elements with `URL` I need to create `~70.000+` static files. As well this static files are needed for google indexing, so we can advertise our products. In case if there is new meta data needed or new item added, I need to run my other program that creates this static files to update everything out of txt file with all items. And we have 2 reserve servers where our sitecore web is. So it like 70k+ files for 9 languages and 3 web servers. It takes a day to recreate everything...

That why I decided to make clear MVC SPA application, and it works great. But...

**I can't add my MVC application or anything except .html files to the current sitecore main app.**

And the question is: how it could be done without losing google indexing and without changing main domain.

```
For example we have now:

www.ourdomain.com/foldername/mystaticfile.html

What I want:

www.ourdomain.com/mynewmvcapplication
```

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore has a settings called `IgnoreUrlPrefixes`. You can add `mynewmvcapplication` to this setting, in that case Sitecore will ignore that path as well as anything under it. [Here](https://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-patchable-ignore-lists/) is a good article which shows you how to update this setting without making an update to Sitecore's config files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Sitecore Redirect Manager Sitecore market place. This it has the capabilities to create your custom url and keeps your search engine rating.
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Redirect_Manager.aspx

Otherwise you can check Custom Link Provider and Custome Item Resolver. This will need more coding than the previous one. A google search with those keywords brings back many results.

Best wishes.